# Client initiated cookie Vs Server initiated cookie

Tags: client

I'm finding similar comments and articles around client side cookies that they are initiated by client and store everything on the client side and server does not store anything. On the other hand server side cookie is set by the server. Server sends it to client that has a unique ID which client sends back with every request. Makes sense. Because this is how server identifies client and same session.

What I don't understand is client side cookie. If there is no ID involved and nothing is saved on the server, then what's the whole point of client sending that cookie to server with every request? And most of all how server identifies its the same client if it has 0 information to compare with and check. That means stateless.

Comment: Can you frame your question in a more security-focused way? As it stands right now, it's probably a better question for stackoverflow.com

Comment: There are no terms like 'server side cookie' vs 'client side cookie'. There are only cookies which are sent in HTTP headers with both requests and responses.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be little confusion .

cookies are the Key/value pair send in response header by web server , and stored locally by your web client

Browser request example:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: host.com
```

Example answer from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: a=10
Set-Cookie: aa=20
```

By server side cookie you mean to say Session stored by Web Server, these are basically use to map your session with the cookies coming in the request header

so both have their respective roles for session to work properly